# Is it safe to use +load in a dynamic framework to set up a quick WKNavigationDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I'm setting up a simple `WKNavigationDelegate` in my dynamic framework to get `WKWebView`'s default user agent string:

```
@interface MyDelegate: NSObject <WKNavigationDelegate>
@end

static NSString *_defaultUserAgent;
static WKWebView *_defaultWebView;
static MyDelegate *_myDelegate;

@implementation MyDelegate
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation {
    DispatchHelper.runOnMain = ^{
        [_defaultWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id __nullable userAgent, NSError * __nullable error) {
            _defaultUserAgent = userAgent;
            _defaultWebView = nil;
            _myDelegate = nil;
        }];
    };
}
@end

@implementation WKWebView (Util)

+ (void)load {
    _myDelegate = MyDelegate.new;
    WKWebView *wkWebView = WKWebView.new;
    wkWebView.navigationDelegate = _myDelegate;
    [wkWebView loadHTMLString:@"<HTML><BODY>TEST</BODY></HTML>" baseURL:nil];
    _defaultWebView = wkWebView;
}

@end
```

Is this safe, or is +load too early to try something like this? In my testing I haven't noticed any issues with it, but after reading [this Mike Ash blog](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html), he says using +load is dangerous/tricky.

Specifically from the blog:

> Keep in mind that there's no autorelease pool present at loading time
>   (usually) so you'll need to wrap your code in one if you're calling
>   into Objective-C stuff.

Am I at risk here by not using @autoreleasepool? I'm confused on how adding

```
+ (void)load {
    @autoreleasepool {
        _myDelegate = MyDelegate.new;
        WKWebView *wkWebView = WKWebView.new;
        wkWebView.navigationDelegate = _myDelegate;
        [wkWebView loadHTMLString:@"<HTML><BODY>TEST</BODY></HTML>" baseURL:nil];
        _defaultWebView = wkWebView;
    }
}
```

helps me here.

Comment: BTW:  The autorelease pool is needed because +load runs outside of a run loop.  There is no automatic autoreleasepool in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+load` is rife with danger and fragility.   I have had to track down many a fun bug due to `+load` surprises over the decades.   In general, it should be avoided.  And when used, it should touch a minimal amount of the rest of the system specifically because you'll be changing the order within which things are initialized at runtime.

I would recommend that you have some kind of initialization hook in your framework that your framework's clients are expected to call in the app, typically during the app delegate's `didFinishLaunching:....` method.

You can put in `assert()s` along other code paths that can warn or raise if the framework was not properly initialized.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm gonna go with an initialization hook as suggested. I did have someone complaining about a crash (message being sent to null `MyDelegate` type). I'm still trying to understand the situation for that occurring as I can't reproduce it myself. Apparently somehow when the system tries to fire the `webView:didFinishNavigation` delegate method, my delegate object has already been deallocated. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the delegate method is fired from the main run loop, but I set up the delegate outside of the main run loop.

Comment: Or maybe the issue is I'm not setting `_defaultWebView.navigationDelegate` back to nil when I set `_myDelegate` to nil. And the system is attempting to fire another delegate method on the webview later.